# How to deal with opening/closing files in Embedded C (STM32)?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I have a question about dealing with files in STM32.
My project requires writing data to microSD card, but i don't know how
to do this to have the best efficiency.
My embedded program is like:

```
while(1)
{
fopen(filename,"a");

// write data to microSD card and send it via radio module

fclose(filename);
}
```

I am afraid that this code can be extremely slow, cause opening/closing
file (especially external file on microSD card) in every loop of my program is expensive.
How can I use fopen and fclose to keep code fast, but also to not loose data in program?

Comment: Why don't you open the file before the loop, and flush the stream in the loop? (Don't argue that this is for "safe" state of the SD card when powered off any time. It its quite the same as your current solution.) -- However, did you benchmark the functions, and are they too slow for your requirements?

Comment: I didn't but it's for sure slowest one i have in my code. Is there any way for CubeIDE to benchmark functions? Im a beginner

Comment: Unless it is **too slow**, I would not think about optimization. But for this you need to measure the times and compare them against your requirements. You have requirements, haven't you? If you don't have requirements, it cannot be too slow. ;-) Anyway, you have several option, among them some functions returning a number of clocks or ticks, or surrounding the functions with setting and resetting a pin, or ... Read the fine manual and use your fantasy.

Comment: My requirements are restricted by radio module, which unfortunately is loosing some data because of slow STM32 code and very fast interrupts upcoming from CAN bus

Comment: Alright, then measure the times and see how they add to the overall performance. Commonly humans are quite bad at guessing the performance bottle necks. If you use a port pin to "signal" the different moments in your control flow, you might like to use different numbers of pulses for the different source locations. This measurement adds to the runtime, of course, but you will get a feeling where the time is "wasted".

Comment: The CAN bus may be doing rather too much in the ISR. You should do minimal processing in the ISR, and signal a task at lower priority than the radio process to deal with the data.  Also use the CAN controller hardware filters to discard messages if no interest with no software overhead.  You should describe these other operations in the question so they can be addressed in an answer.  A more holistic/architectural solution is likely to have greater impact than worrying about filesystem performance issues over which you have little control.

Comment: What filesystem are you using?  The CubeMX provided filesystem the ELM FatFs library, which is not intrinsically power-fail safe.  There are (non-free) powerfail safe FAT filesystems that use journaling.  Or you could use something like LittleFS for both power fail safety and better performance (FAT slows down considerably for example when a directory has a large number of files). If you need to access the volume on a PC, you will have to use Linux (or perhaps WSL) and add support for LittleFS https://www.thevtool.com/mounting-littlefs-on-linux-machine/

Answer (score 2):

The slowest part of this system is likely to be the SD card itself. Not only that; it will be variable - it will stream data consistently until it meets some physical or buffer boundary intrinsic to the specific card at which point it will stall for several milliseconds.  Also the cards themselves vary widely, even for the same speed rating.

If you have real-time deadlines, writing to the SD card is ill-advised.  Instead you might do  better to use an RTOS and perform the SD card write in a lower priority task than the radio task, passing the data to the file task via a queue long enough to provide buffering to smooth out the file system latency.

Either way, if you are writing in small chunks, you would improve performance considerably by buffering data and writing in larger chunks that match the filesystem buffer size (typically 512 bytes).  So rather than writing data as it arrives, you'd collate it in a buffer and write it when it reached the optimal chunk size.  If using the RTOS method, you might have one task collating the data from the queue, then a third, even lower priority task with an input queue of at least two blocks to actually write the SD card.